# Virtual Keypad (Keith Wood) closes itself on every click when initialized on textboxes inside a JQuery Dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

#### UPDATE -- jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLURx/4/

On my main screen, I have one inline instance of the virtual keypad that works fine.

There are links in a table on this screen that will open a JQuery Dialog that contains another table, where one of the columns is a textbox for each row. I initialize a keypad for every textbox that is generated, so that the user will have a popup keypad for each box to enter some numbers.

It all works up to this point. I had to change the z-index of the popup keypads so that they appeared above the dialog, but now I can click on every box and the keypad will slide in as it should. The problem happens whenever I **click** any of the buttons on the keypads. Every keypad, upon clicking any button, will close itself and open up a keypad above the **top** row in the table. This top keypad will stay open upon being clicked, but it does **not** add text to any field.

jQuery function for dialog / initializing popup keypads:

```
$(function () {
        var createdPads = []; 
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: '95%',
            height: 1000,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#dialog :text').each(function () {
                    $(this).keypad({
                        keypadOnly: false,
                        keypadClass: 'miniPad'
                    });
                    createdPads.push(this);
                });
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                for (i = 0; i < createdPads.length; i++) {
                    createdPads[i].remove();//removing created keypads because they were affecting the previous inline keypad 
                }
                $('#<%=enterNumberBox.ClientID%>').blur();//removing focus from original field
                var tbl = $('#<%=gvData.ClientID%>');
                if (tbl.is(":visible")) { //scrolling back down to results after dialog close
                    $(window).scrollTop(tbl.position().top);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS-Class for the popup keypads:

```
.miniPad{
    z-index: 9999 !important; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
    <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input type="text"/></span><!--to prevent autofocus-->    
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvItemData"></asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="updateStagedButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return validateUpdate();" />
</div>
```

I'll add a screenshot of what I'm talking about once I have enough rep.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you perhaps set up a jsfiddle.net for this so we can see the issue?

Comment: @Rob I don't think there exists a URI for Keith Wood's keypad plugin, so I'm not sure how I could add that to the fiddle to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Sure he won't mind if it's just for a fiddle http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.keypad.js

Comment: @Rob I added a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLURx/4/ . Thanks

Comment: I have been 'fiddling' and can see that there is some issue with the dialog as when you render the inputs elsewhere it behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Solved it :-)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Tut8M/

As surmised, this is indeed to do with the dialog.  It by default prevents any interactions with elements that are not a child of it which causes problems when they are absolutely positioned to *appear* to be.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-_allowInteraction

Thankfully there is a way we can override this and that is by setting the 
`_allowIteraction()` function

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function (e) {
        return !!$(e.target).parents(".miniPad") || this._super(event);
    };
```

This checks to see if the interacted upon elements have a parent which has a class of `miniPad` and if it does then it allows it.  This fixes things nicely.